# Thread is not returning back from SwingUtilities.invokeLater to main thread

Tags: java, swing, invokelater

I am writing my code in swing. To launch a private function of another class that can be called in awt thread . i simply write the code of that function in my class in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` thread.

```
main() {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        //code of private function

    });

}
```

but after executing this control is not coming back to main thread. Can anyone suggest what is happening and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

`SwingUtilities.invokeLater` will not block the execution of the current thread. If believe it does, you can simply do

```
System.out.println("Before");

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //code of private function
        }
    });

System.out.println("After");
```

and you will see `Before` and `After` printed right after each other more or less immediately.

(Make sure you haven't accidentally used `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`.)

Answer (score 1):

`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` will execute the code in the EDT as you have correctly stated. `main` thread continues its execution right after the call of `invokeLater`. You may not see the main thread if you execute the program in debugger and having a breakpoint somewhere in the code executed in EDT, but the `main` thread is executed for sure.